# How to retrieve an entire column from a data table using it's column name

Tags: c#, datatable, datacolumn

I have a data table that looks like this

```
|id | foo | bar |
| 0 | 321 | 33  |
| 1 | 100 |  4  |
| 2 | 355 | 23  |
```

I want to retrive an entire column using the column name as an argument

Something like

```
GetColumn(dataTable, "foo")
```

That would return

```
| foo | 
| 321 | 
| 100 | 
| 355 |
```

Is there something that does that?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so we can better assist you.

Comment: What data type do you expect from `GetColumn`? Can you write a declaration for `GetColumn`? Is your data table actually a `DataTable`?

Comment: `dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["foo"]).ToList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("foo", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("bar", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0 , 321 , 33  });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1 , 100 , 4  });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2 , 355 , 23  });

            List<int> results = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("foo")).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if user wants to add this somewhere else, you know call it; with specified object/datatable and column name?

Comment: That has nothing to do with the answer.

Comment: `I want to retrive an entire column using the column name as an argument` it's pretty obvious it is... Currently this can't be re-used anywhere....

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ The OP asked if there was something like `GetColumn(DataTable Table, string ColumnName)`. And there isn't. This answer does exactly what the OP asked for, it gives a list of values for a given column. If the user wants more functionality, that's up to them.

Comment: How does `GetColumn(dataTable, "foo")` and `That would return` not indicate the user is asking for a function? @Patrick Tucci

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ because the original post doesn't explicitly ask for that. It's a dangerous precedent to require that answers on StackOverflow must infer additional and unspecified functionality. If the user needed a method that matches the signature they made up in their question, they should have explicitly asked for it. There's more than enough information here for the user to do that themselves if they need it.

Comment: Understand, `It's a dangerous precedent to require that answers on StackOverflow must infer additional and unspecified functionality`, did the OP ask for a `linq` solution, does the OP even know what `linq` does/is? My point is the OP didn't provide enough detail to even answer this adequately. Currently the answers are based on assumptions, not facts or information the OP left out. The answer provided, does it work, yes; can it be improved, yes; is it the right solution, *we don't know*...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ then the solution is to downvote the question. This answer isn't wrong because the question may or may not be clear. With the information given, this is an acceptable solution. It's also not up to posters to verify the language competency of the OP before answering. Also, any .NET developers who don't know the basics of Linq should drop everything and go learn them. C# is almost a different language with and without Linq (an exaggeration, but not by much).

Comment: `This answer isn't wrong because the question may or may not be clear`, then how do we know this is ***the right answer*** to the OP problem, just because it works?

Comment: It is up to the OP to determine the type of solution.  You cannot expect a beginner to know the different type of solutions and to show more than one type option is great experience for a beginner.  From a posting you often cannot tell a persons knowledge.  Some people ask for solutions using methods that are not appropriate for the issue.  Others ask for solutions that are not efficient solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly. But you could do something like:

```
private List<string> GetColumnValues(string columnName, DataTable dataTable)
{
    var colValues = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
    {
        var value = row[columnName];
        if (value != null)
        {
            colValues.Add((string)value);
        }
    }
    return colValues;
}
```

If you want something that would work with other primitive types (int, decimal, bool etc), you may want to read up on `C# generics` and implement a generic method.

Comment: Please test code before posting a solution. Also IMHO, the OP needs to provide more information so we can actually help them find what they are doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry realize now... I am not on ide to write the entire thing. But what is wrong with that code?

Comment: `what is wrong with that code`, it doesn't work... the list *wasn't* initialized at first, what happens when `row["colName"]` is null, would it be a possibility the columns could have duplicate strings etc...? Also, it looks like the user has `int` values, why would you declare a `List<string>`?